# Need help in coding night mode wordpress webiste which will automatically trigger based on 7pm to 7am (Like instagram) but for my website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to have a javascript code which checks if current time is between 7pm and 7am. If so it should change the background color on my website to X. If the current time is not between 7pm and 7am the background color should be the original of the wordpress theme. The time should be automatically known from the users browser and according to that the function should trigger.

**I saw this code online it triggers users time**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'moment.min.js';?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'moment-timezone.js';?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'moment-timezone-data.js';?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'jquery-1.9.0.min.js';?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'jstz-1.0.4.min.js';?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tz = jstz.determine();
  var current_time= moment.tz().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');;
  alert(current_time);
});
```

the files needed to trigger the time
[Download the necessary files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uqcP3qPIBrjfmSc-g5Wm8Jo-onENRg5O/view?usp=sharing)

If you have any other method feel free to suggest

Comment: Can you tell us whats going wrong with the code currently?

Comment: i am using it in the plugins section i am making a plugin so its not working there

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward with some basic javascript and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   // get today's info

   var d = new Date();

   // get the hour of the day - between 1 & 24

   var time = d.getHours();
   
   // check if hour is at 7pm or later

   if (time >= 19) { 

     $('.background').css('background-color', '#000');
     
     // check if time is 7am or earlier

   } else if (time <= 7) {

     $('.background').css('background-color', '#000');
   } else {
     
     // you can remove this else statement is meant to demonstrate what would happen between 7am and 7pm if there was not a default
     
     $('.background').css('background-color', 'orange');
   
   }

});
.background {

width: 500px;
height: 500px;
background-color: blue;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: The brackets at the end were out of order that was likely causing the issue.  I have add a working snippet here.  before 7am and after 7pm the block should be black, any other time it will be orange.